# Pytest: Nested use of request fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'd like to get some help on how to run pytests with multiple layers of parameterized pytest fixtures.

I have a global request-based fixture for selecting a base implementation of the system I'd like to test:

```py
@fixture()
def a_provider():
    yield 'a'


@fixture()
def b_provider():
    yield 'b'


@fixture(params=["a_provider", "b_provider"])
def letter_provider(request):
    yield request.getfixturevalue(request.param)
```

I'd like to now run some additionally-parametrized tests against different test cases on the backend.

```py
@fixture()
def one(letter_provider):
    yield letter_provider * 1


@fixture()
def two(letter_provider):
    yield letter_provider * 2


@fixture(params=["one", "two"])
def letter_cases(request):
    yield request.getfixturevalue(request.param)
```

Using these two layers of fixtures, I'd like to be able to run both tests parameterised by the base-implementation.

```py
def test_foo(letter_provider):
    """
    Should run once for "a" and once for "b"
    """
    assert letter_provider in {"a", "b"}
```

And tests that use all the additional cases

```py
def test_bar(letter_cases):
    """
    test should be executed 4 times for : a, aa, b, bb
    """
    assert letter_cases in {
        "a", "aa",
        "b", "bb",
    }
```

At the moment, my test setup fails with:

```
test setup failed
'letter_provider'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
letter_provider

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
The requested fixture has no parameter defined for test:
    tests/test_example.py::test_bar[one]

Requested fixture 'letter_provider' defined in:
tests/test_example.py:15
```

How could I set up my test suite to run these levels of parameterization?

Comment: I can't test that right now, but IIRC this can be fixed by providing the dependency fixtures in the fixture signature, e.g. `def letter_cases(request, one, two): ...`.

Comment: @hoefling this works. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the fixture cache is filled with `one` and `two` fixture values when calling `getfixturevalue()` by adding both fixtures as `letter_cases` dependencies:

```
@fixture(params=["one", "two"])
def letter_cases(request, one, two):
    yield request.getfixturevalue(request.param)
```